# VS Code - Make jsx intellisense works for simple ".js" files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm working with VS Code, the intellisense easing the writing of jsx code works only when the editor is set on "Javascript React" file. How make the intellisense when my editor is simple set on "Javascript".

It would allow me to create simple ".js" file benefiting by the same way of the jsx intellisense.

Thanks

Comment: any reason you aren't using `.jsx`?

Comment: for the convenience my captain

Comment: just so you know this could cause confusion for others reading your code

Comment: yep to keep in mind when making the choice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this setting in your user settings file:

```
"files.associations": {
   "*.js": "javascriptreact"
}
```

My VSCode version: 1.24.1